# Just installed Arduino IDE 1.8.4 and want to program Arduino via a USB port

Tags: usb, arduino, ide

I just installed Arduino IDE 1.8.4 on a RPi3 and want to program Arduino via a USB port.  The application seems to run fine except - the Tools->Port->"Serial ports" is grayed out.  How to I assign/enable a Pi3 USB port for the Arduino IDE?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do anything.

If the Arduino USB is detected it should be shown.

You can check `/dev/tty*` to see if the Pi has detected the serial device; this is normally `/dev/ttyACM0` with an Arduino.

Many of the cheap Chinese clones had non-standard USB chips, which are not detected, and are notoriously unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

The cheap arduino clones use the CH340G Chip to control the uploading via USB, a different chip than the authentic arduinos. I have a handful of them that spontaneously like to not work with my IDE.

This site might give you a little more insight than I can:

https://kig.re/2014/12/31/how-to-use-arduino-nano-mini-pro-with-CH340G-on-mac-osx-yosemite.html

Basically, sometimes you might need to install a 'driver' for your system to be able to communicate with the chip over USB. Once installed, you should be able to see the device in your Tools -> Port options.

Another thing you might need to consider if you didn't know, is there are two different types of Arduino IDE, and I recommend using .cc version if you are not using that already.